# How to find the longest word in list?

Tags: haskell

I can't get my mind in a functional mindset to solve this problem in a simple way that could also work for very long lists. If you have a list like:

```
["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
```

I can tell what the length of the longest word is pretty simply with:

```
maximum $ map length ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
```

How would I modify the previous statement to return the string *three*?

Comment: @Mark Byers Return the first occurrence of the longest word.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Using [`maximumBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:maximumBy), [`on`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Function.html#v:on) and [`compare`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Ord.html#v:compare) you can write the expression like this:

```
import Data.List (maximumBy)
import Data.Function (on)

maximumBy (compare `on` length)  ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
```

Comment: `compare \`on\` length` is `comparing length` where `comparing` is from `Data.Ord`.

Comment: Really elegant. Nice solution.

Answer (score 13):

btw, if one had no ready-to-use `maximumBy`, a simple way would be the decorate-sort-undecorate pattern/idiom (which works in other languages like Python or Scheme as well):

```
snd $ maximum $ map (\x -> (length x, x)) ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
```

But since the original payload is also part of the sort-key, the result is not always the first occurrence of the longest word (in this case there was only one word with the longest length)

Comment: Even with `maximumBy`, this is useful.  The `maximumBy` function will recalculate the length (or whichever comparison function is being used) of the longest current token at each comparison, whereas decorate-sort-undecorate only calculates the length once.  This version is noticeably more efficient even with modest-sized inputs.  Of course, if you're using lists of any length, you probably shouldn't be using lists.

Comment: @John if you're just doing a single pass over a stream of data, a list of any length is perfectly fine. Now strings on the other hand...

Comment: @John, thanks for pointing out the issue of `maximum(By)` re-evaluating `max`, which I wasn't aware of and surprised me a bit (implementing `maximum` by simply `foldl1 max` is without doubt elegant nevertheless)

Comment: @sclv, yes, that's a hasty over-generalization.  As you say, what's important is how the data is consumed.

Comment: @hvr, ghc isn't nearly as aggressive about sharing values as one might expect (or hope).  Apparently it's very difficult to guarantee sharing won't be much less efficient than re-calculating, so ghc requires sharing be made explicit with let-bound expressions.  And although the `maximumBy` implementation is very elegant, it doesn't share computations.

Comment: Or, pointlessly, `longestWord = snd . maximum . map (\x -> (length x, x))`

Comment: @Dan: That's not fully pointless: `longestWord = snd . maximum . map (length &&& id)` is.

Comment: @hvr: The problem with the decorate method is that it requires that x have an Ord instance, even though you're only comparing the decorations.  For performance reasons, you may use the decorate method along with `maximumBy fst` to avoid the need for Ord on the list elements themselves.

Answer (score 10):

This function(or even library) doesn't seem to be well known, but Haskell actually has a module called `Data.Ord` which contains the function `comparing` which is almost like using `Data.Function.on` in the top answer, except the code ends up more idiomatic.

```
g>import Data.Ord
g>import Data.List
g>let getLongestElement = maximumBy (comparing length)
getLongestElement :: [[a]] -> [a]
g>getLongestElement ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
"three"
```

The code practically reads like English. "Get maximum by comparing length."

Comment: Others disagree, and think `comparing` is a silly special case. I don't care, myself, but I've heard experienced people complain about it.

Answer (score 3):

`maximumBy` `(\x -> (x, length x))`, `fst`, and `snd` in a straightforward composition do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

To compute `length a`, you need to traverse the entire list `a`. In this particular use case, you are only concerned about the longest word, and not exactly how long they are, so you may write a function that only go as far as it is needed in each list to determine which one is the longest. This may save you some processing:

```
module Main where

main = putStrLn $ longestWordInList ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

longestWordInList = go ""
  where go result [] = result
        go result (x:xs) = let result' = longestWord result x in
                               result' `seq` go result' xs

longestWord a b = go a b a b
  where go a _ _ [] = a
        go _ b [] _ = b
        go a b (_:as) (_:bs) = go a b as bs
```

Comment: You don't need so many arguments to `go`. Just use different names and refer to the ones in the outer scope. `longestWord a b = go a b where go a' _ = a ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
foldl (\accmax xs -> if length accmax < length xs then xs else accmax) [] ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
```